# WPF Avalon Edit Make text upper case

Tags: wpf, runtime-error, avalonedit

I am using C# WPF with Avalon Edit Text Box.

I am trying to make all of the text in the text box uppercase and I get an error with additional message 'No undo group should be open at this point'.

I am using the following code:

```
a.Text = a.Text.ToUpper();
```

where "a" is the AvalonEdit.TextEditor

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `TextEditor.Text` property has the side-effect of clearing the undo stack (just as with the normal WPF `TextBox`). Clearing the undo stack is only allowed when there's no open undo group.

If you did not intend to clear the undo stack, use the methods on `textEditor.Document` instead to modify the document. You'll want to avoid replacing the whole text, because that would also reset the selection and caret position (after all, AvalonEdit can't know how your new text is related to the old text).

If you do want to clear the undo stack (e.g. you're switching the view to a different document), you'll have to figure out why an undo group is open. Most likely, your code is running from the event handler of an event that is called while the undo group is still open (e.g. `document.TextChanged`) -- you might want to switch to a different event instead (e.g. `document.UpdateFinished` is called after the undo group was closed).

If all you want to do is to upper-case text as it is being input, it's better to modify the text before it is added to the document: handle the `TextArea.TextEntering` event to cancel any lower-case input (set `e.Handled = true;`), and instead call `TextArea.PerformTextInput()` to repeat the text input process with the corresponding upper-case text instead.

For copy-paste, you could handle the attached `DataObject.PastingEvent` and modify the data to be pasted.